# Checkboxes stay checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few checkboxes that need to stay checked after a page refresh.
But they or need to be all checked to stay checked after refresh, either if only a few are checked, they don't stay checked after refresh.

Any ideas on how do I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Persist checkboxes 1</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <input type="checkbox" class="option">

      <input type="checkbox" class="option">

      <input type="checkbox" class="option">

      <input type="checkbox" class="option">

      <input type="checkbox" class="option">

      <input type="checkbox" class="option">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(".option").on("change", function(){
        var checkboxValues = {};
        $(".option").each(function(){
          checkboxValues[this.className] = this.checked;
        });
        $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 1, path: '/' })
      });

      function repopulateCheckboxes(){
        var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
        if(checkboxValues){
          Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = checkboxValues[element];
            $("." + element).prop('checked', checked);
          });
        }
      }

      $.cookie.json = true;
      repopulateCheckboxes();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't have duplicate ids, they must be unique to each page.

Comment: @zer00ne I know, but when I use classes, [this.className] doesn't work, thats the problem.

Comment: Your elements have no class attribute.

Comment: @squint if I replace the ids with classes, [this.className] does not work for some reason

Comment: You really need to post the code you're actually asking about. You're asking about one thing but posted something else.

Comment: @squint edited. Sorry for missleading

Comment: Every class is the same, so this: `checkboxValues[this.className] = this.checked;` is always going to be assigning the `option` property, which can naturally only hold one value. I think what you mean to do is to keep the class as it is so you can select them all at once, but then provide a *unique* ID for each option, and use that ID in the object. `checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;` and use the ID so set the property again. `$("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);`

Comment: ...I posted an answer and made it a community wiki in case you feel you need to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the class on each input, but also give each a unique ID if you wish to have something unique to use in the storage object.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="opt1" class="option">

  <input type="checkbox" id="opt2" class="option">

  <input type="checkbox" id="opt3" class="option">

  <input type="checkbox" id="opt4" class="option">

  <input type="checkbox" id="opt5" class="option">

  <input type="checkbox" id="opt6" class="option">
```

You can then still select the elements at once by their class, but use the `.id` to store the items in the object, and to reset them.

```
  $(".option").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};

    $(".option").each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });

    $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 1, path: '/' })
  });

  function repopulateCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');

    if(checkboxValues){
      Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(id) {
        $("#" + id).prop('checked', checkboxValues[id]);
      });
    }
  }

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateCheckboxes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is class name. Since all checkboxes have same class. This line `checkboxValues[this.className] = this.checked;` ends-up with only one entry i.e `{'option' : true}` if last one is checked else `{'option' : false}`.

In below code snippet, I am using array and element index to persist state.

```js
$.cookie.json = true;

$(function() {
  var options = $.cookie('options');
  var chkbxs = $('.option');
  console.log('options', options);
  if (options) {
    $.each(options, function(i, chkd) {
      chkbxs.eq(i).prop('checked', chkd);
    });
  }

  chkbxs.on('change', function() {
    options = chkbxs.map(function(_, chk) {
      return chk.checked;
    }).get();
    console.log('options', options);
    $.cookie('options', options);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" class="option">
<input type="checkbox" class="option">
<input type="checkbox" class="option">
<input type="checkbox" class="option">
<input type="checkbox" class="option">
<input type="checkbox" class="option">
```

Answer (score -1):

your jquery is loaded from google website . so the js event of the loaded completing event , you coded these code should stay in window.load event and it does work

window.load = function () {

```
     //your performing code
```

}